# How to pick 3D-Objects with Mouse in FireMonkey at Runtime

Tags: delphi, object, 3d, firemonkey

i have searched now for a long time and found no answer. Please give me a little help. I have various 3D-objects in a TVieport3D and want to pick them in runtime-mode with my mouse. But i don't know how to do this. Thank you

Comment: I search the same with the possibility to drag&drop(move) the object in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any special action to achive picking in Firemonkey. Each 3-d object is already a component which can responde to mouse actions. If your objects are designtime objects, just select them in the viewport and handle their ONMouseClick events, if they are runtime created, then assign your pick event to their OnMOuseclick event properties in runtime.

Comment: *Please do not include a 'signature' in your posts, and do not include your website link*. Your user box serves as a signature, and your profile can include your link. I am removing your link from your post(s); do not add it back in, or your posts could be mistaken for spam.